# nodejs How to get mysql data if insert new row in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, webrtc

i am stuck in geting mysql table data in real time.i have some situation to get real time data like if in table insert new row then nodejs response new row are insert in table. if any one have any solution without calling interval function please let me know

thank you

Comment: You cant send response of a request more than once, what you can do is that, in post save hook you can update the front end to send another request by socket